# Fix 'variable undefined' in Access VBA for turnig off automatic Calculation with 'Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual'

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to speed up a Module with Access VBA which write some Data to Excel-Files.
The problem is, that in the row "objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual" VBA says that 'xlCalculationManual' is an 'undefined variable'.
Same for 'xlCalculationAutomatic'.
Does anyone knows how to fix it?

I tried to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation) by define the values for 'xlCalculationManual' as -4135 (as Const and as Integer, both didn't work) and for 'xlCalculationAutomatic' -4105. (See link).

```
'First try
[...]
Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")    
objExcel.Application.Visible = False
objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
[...]
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
[...]

'Second try
[...]
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim xlCalculationManual As Integer
xlCalculationManual = -4135
Dim xlCalculationAutomatic As Integer
xlCalculationAutomatic = -4105

Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")    
objExcel.Application.Visible = False
objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
[...]
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
[...]

'Third try
[...]
Dim objExcel As Object
Const xlCalculationManual = -4135
Const xlCalculationAutomatic = -4105
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")    
objExcel.Application.Visible = False
objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
[...]
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
[...]

'Forth try
[...]
Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")    
objExcel.Application.Visible = False
objExcel.Application.Calculation = -4135
[...]
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Calculation = -4105
[...]
```

Comment: What exactly happened with the third and fourth tries?

Comment: @Rory Both gave the same Error-Message: Laufzeitfehler '1004': Die Calculation-Eigenschaft des Application-Objektes kann nicht festgelegt werden. (Or: Runtime Error '1004': The The Calculation property of the Application object can not be set.)

Comment: Try adding a new blank workbook (`objexcel.workbooks.add`) before changing the calculation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you use late binding. Switch to *early binding*:

- set a Reference to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- modify code -

like this:

```
 Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
```

Then your code will know the enums and constants of Excel.